# Model/View delegate component common parts

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qml, qtquick2

I have a custom c++ model class which inherits from [`QAbstractListModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html). And as a view I use [`GridView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html).
So [`GridView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html) constructs as many components as [`QAbstractItemModel::rowCount()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowCount). But as a delegate I
use a complex component. With "complex" I mean that it has animations.

```
property bool animate: false
delegate: Rectangle {
    SequentialAnimation on color {
        running: view.animate
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        ColorAnimation { from: "blue"; to: "#33FFFF"; duration: 1200 }
        ColorAnimation { from: "#33FFFF"; to: "blue"; duration: 1200 }
    }
}
```

What I want to ask is, shall I move the common parts of the delegate one layer up and use binding and
put up with the signal and slots mechanism overhead instead of constructing unnecessary animation objects
for all model elements?

```
delegate: Rectangle {
    color: view.delegateColorAnimation
}
property bool animate: false
property color delegateColorAnimation
SequentialAnimation on delegateColorAnimation {
    running: animate
    loops: Animation.Infinite
    ColorAnimation { from: "blue"; to: "#33FFFF"; duration: 1200 }
    ColorAnimation { from: "#33FFFF"; to: "blue"; duration: 1200 }
}
```

I know signal and slots mechanism overhead is negligible but I am confused because of the special
syntax for animation ([`Animation on property`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-animations.html#using-predefined-targets-and-properties)). Is there still a binding mechanism running on the
background? Or is there any magic?

If there isn't any magic for this syntax, and updating the property still relies on the binding mechanism,
probably the second option would be the better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'on' syntax is explained here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#property-value-sources

I would go for less of `Animation` objects, because nowadays it's all about cache-friendliness, so going through less of the memory is better.

The second option calculate animation once, while the first option do it per each item.